# Deploying to an Azure Web App via ARM/msdeploy without deleting existing files

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy, azure-resource-manager

When deploying to an Azure Web App (aka Azure App Service) using regular msdeploy (a.k.a WebDeploy, used for Visual Studio or VSTS publishing), you can choose to *not* delete existing files at the destination.

But when using the ARM `extensions/msdeploy` provider (e.g. via an ARM template), existing files are always deleted by default. Is there a way to override this and not blow away existing files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way Azure Web App supports the DoNotDeleteRule is via the [**addOnPackages**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createinstancemsdeployoperation) schema element.

**addOnPackages** use the DoNotDelete rule implicitly.  So, if you want to apply a package without deleting files in the existing site, you specify it in the addOnPackages array, and then **don't** define anything in the outer MSDeploy object.  e.g.:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "appName": {
                "value": "mysite"
            },
            "location":{
                "value": "USAAnywhere"
            }
        },
        "template": {
            "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0-r188+188.764a8a7798ecc6ebb752343c6f8e6be2903ba711",
            "parameters": {
                "appName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
                            "name": "MSDeploy",
                            "type": "Extensions",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('appName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "addOnPackages" : [
                                    {
                                        "packageUri": "https://mystorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/package/my_webdeploy_package.zip",
                                        "AppOffline": true,
                                        "setParameters": {
                                            "IIS Web Application Name": "[parameters('appName')]",
                                         }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties" : {}
                }
            ]
        },
        "mode": "Incremental"
    }
}
```

The **addOnPackages** also allows multiple packages in a single MSDeploy ARM template; The outer one will delete the files for the existing site, and the addOnPackages are additive and will not delete the outer package.  e.g.:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "appName": {
                "value": "mysite"
            },
            "location":{
                "value": "USAAnywhere"
            }
        },
        "template": {
            "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0-r188+188.764a8a7798ecc6ebb752343c6f8e6be2903ba711",
            "parameters": {
                "appName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
                            "name": "MSDeploy",
                            "type": "Extensions",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('appName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "packageUri": "https://mystorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/package/my_webdeploy_package.zip",
                                "dbType": "None",
                                "connectionString": "",
                                "AppOffline": true,
                                "SkipAppData": true,
                                "setParameters": {
                                    "IIS Web Application Name": "[parameters('appName')]"
                                },
                                "addOnPackages" : [
                                    {
                                        "packageUri": "https://mystorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/package/my_first_add_on_package.zip",
                                        "AppOffline": true,
                                        "setParameters": {
                                            "IIS Web Application Name": "[parameters('appName')]",
                                         }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "packageUri": "https://mystorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/package/my_second_add_on_package.zip",
                                        "setParameters": {
                                            "IIS Web Application Name": "[parameters('appName')]",
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties" : {}
                }
            ]
        },
        "mode": "Incremental"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does AppOffline and SkipAppData parameters mean?

Comment: @juvchan : `"appOffline" : true` is the equivalent of the msdeploy `-enableRule:AppOffline` command line option.  It is `false` (off) by default.  `"skipAppData" : true` is the equivalent of the msdeploy `-skip:objectname='dirPath',absolutepath=App_Data`.